# GAE Datastore Java data type for date/time values

Tags: google-app-engine, java.util.date

Both `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date` return the following when trying to persist them in the datastore.

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Attempt to handle persistence for object using datastore-identity yet StoreManager for this datastore doesn't support that identity type
```

What data types do you use for date/time values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the problem is with the date field?  It sounds more like your object is not set up right to work in GAE - do you have a primary key field set up on your entity?  Is your code top secret or can you show us your entity code?

Comment: Yes, that was it, the persistentce capable annotation wasn't there.